# TemplateDoesNotExist at /post/3

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a template that should show the details of a post when you request it, but when you request it, there is a TemplateDoesNotExist error in /post/3.
It shows me, but the rest of the templates are working correctly except for this one

I feel that somewhere I should have used `.`, but instead I used `/` or vice versa

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    

class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/post')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} - {self.body[:30]}..."
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [

    path('post/<int:pk>', views.detalis, name='post')
]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('home_app.urls')),
    path('',include('account.urls')),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post 


def detalis(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post-detalis.html', {'post': post})
```

setting.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]


MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Other templates work fine, only the detail page does not work

Comment: likely typo: `post-details.html` is `post-detalis.html`